# What was Amberle Elessedil holding if she is the seed herself?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-shannara-chronicles

At the end of [The Shannara Chronicles](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1051220/), [Amberle Elessedil](http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Amberle_Elessedil) (the princess) walks into the fire (to another world/dimension) to obtain the seeds to save the [Ellcrys](http://shannara.wikia.com/wiki/Ellcrys).

You can see her holding a seed in the series (some red-ish color) but then the plot turns and a woman appears in the other world and tells Amberle that she, ***herself***, is the seed.

**Q**: So what was she holding then, since they already went through a lot of trouble and sacrificing almost all the blood from the rover?

Comment: This might not be helpful, not an official source anyway, but i read a theory somewhere that the seed was like a catalyst for her transformation. For all i know, there is no official answer available.

Comment: @Lettmannen do you have a link of that source by any chance?

Comment: http://www.tor.com/2015/12/16/rereading-the-elfstones-of-shannara-chapters-48-and-49/